# React serverside, webpack

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I want to render a React app on the serverside and have dependencies handling problems.

More precisely, I want to load jquery from cdn and be able to do

```
require('jquery')
```

in my application's files. Everything works well on the client side, I have a webpack config file wich looks like this:

```
# webpack.config.js 
externals : {
    "jquery": "jQuery",
}
```

and jquery is simply loaded in an html file:

```
# index.html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am not able to make this work serverside. If I understand well, this has nothing to do with webpack, which is a only a bundler and it's job is not to actually load the files. Once again, if I understand well, this should be done by my node server which actually renders the React component.

```
# server.js
var reactRender = require('react-render');
reactRender({path: '/abs/path/to/component.js', ...});
```

The problem is that require('jquery') does not work in this context. 
Here ([using webpack on server side of nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911491/using-webpack-on-server-side-of-nodejs)) I found an example on how to use webpack serverside but it does not adress the issue of externals components not installed in node_modules.

I also tried to use script.js (https://github.com/ded/script.js) to first load jquery from CDN and then render the app, but it requires the document component, which is undefined serverside.

```
# this does not work
$script(['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'], 'bundle');
$script.ready('bundle', function() {
    reactRender(...)
});
```

Any thought is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: After answering, I realized you actually need to use jquery functionality server-side, is that right?  If so I can provide another answer that may work for you.

Comment: Hi cspotcode, sure, I need jquery serverside. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've used [domino](https://github.com/fgnass/domino) combined with jquery to manipulate HTML server-side.  Domino is a JavaScript implementation of the DOM.  I'm not a react expert, but this may work for you:

```
npm install --save domino jquery
```

And then:

```
// Create a window object.  See also: https://github.com/fgnass/domino#usage
const domino = require('domino');
const window = domino.createWindow('');
const document = window.document;

// Create a jquery instance
const $ = require('jquery')(window);
```

Comment: Thanks cspotcode, I will have a look at it and accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

why not just conditionally set the `externals` property based on where you're calling webpack? using an environment variable or something

Comment: you mean something like try { var $ = require('jquery') } catch(e) { var $ } in my files? The problem is I need it on server side.